# Using python or pandas to merge many files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have multiple files (up to 20 or more) to merge based on certain criteria. Three file examples are below:

```
File1           
ID  Type    Condition   Colour
113884  M   Good    Green
123456  M   Good    Blue
178101  U   Good    Yellow
245645  U   Good    Red
256178  X   Fair    Green
803989  X   Poor    Red

File2           
ID  Type    Condition   Colour
113884  M   Good    Green
123456  M   Good    Blue
172221  M   Poor    Red
178101  U   Good    Yellow
256178  X   Fair    Green

File 3          
ID  Type    Condition   Colour
113884  M   Good    Green
123456  M   Good    Blue
172221  M   Poor    Red
178101  U   Good    Yellow
178101  U   Good    Yellow
256178  X   Fair    Green
286762  Q   Good    Purple
```

I want to extract and merge similar information in these files as in the required output below. In all files any row with 'Type' M and Q are extracted along with their IDs, and so in the output file the file names then become columns of fields indicating 'yes' or 'no' if the ID and Type were contained in the file or not.

Required output (.csv):

```
ID  Type    File 1  File2   File3
113884  M   Yes Yes Yes
123456  M   Yes Yes Yes
172221  M   No  Yes Yes
286762  Q   No  No  Yes
```

Here's my insufficient attempt:

```
import os, glob

all_line =[]
for file in golob.glob('*.txt'):
    infile = open('file', 'r')
    for line in file:
        line=line.strip.split('\t')
        if line[1]=='M' or line[1]=='Q':
            all_line.append(line)
```

I'm not sure how to do this using python or pandas. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: Is that the exact format of the file?

Comment: Yes. Row numbers of files are not the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC you can do it this way:

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

files = glob.glob(r'D:\temp\.data\File*.csv')

def merge_files(files, **kwargs):
    dfs = []
    for f in files:
        dfs.append(
            pd.read_csv(f, delim_whitespace=True, usecols=['ID','Type'])
              .query("Type in ['M','Q']")
              .drop_duplicates()
              .assign(col=0)
              .rename(columns={'col':os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(f))[0]})
              .set_index(['ID','Type'])
        )
    return pd.concat(dfs, axis=1).notnull()


result = merge_files(files).reset_index()
print(result)
```

Output:

```
       ID Type  File1  File2 File3
0  113884    M   True   True  True
1  123456    M   True   True  True
2  172221    M  False   True  True
3  286762    Q  False  False  True
```

Comment: Thanks MaxU. After running the code, I got the following error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 20, in <module>
    result = merge_files(files).reset_index()
  File "test.py", line 17, in merge_files
    return pd.concat(dfs, axis=1).notnull()
  File "/home/rob/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tools/merge.py", line 846, in concat

Comment: Remaining part of the long error: return op.get_result()
  File "/home/rob/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tools/merge.py", line 1031, in get_result
    indexers[ax] = obj_labels.reindex(new_labels)[1]
  File "/home/rob/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/indexes/multi.py", line 1422, in reindex
    raise Exception("cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!")
Exception: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!

Comment: Thanks so much MaxU. I really appreciate your help. It works fine. I tried unsuccessfully to replace True and False with '+' and '-' like this: df = pd.DataFrame(result), df = df.replace(['True', 'False'], ['+','-']). What's the right way to do this? How can I output 'color' column in addition to 'ID' and 'Type'? I added usecols=['ID','Type', 'Color'] but it didn't work.

Comment: @user27976, could you please open a new question with a small reproducible sample data set and expected (desired) data set?